# How do i call angularjs function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to call my AngularJs function from JavaScript

**JavaScript**

```
function loadData1() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    var a = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    if (a=="organisationUnits") {
        getorganisationUnits();
    }
}
```

**AngularJs**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    //angular.element('#myCtrl').scope().getorganisationUnits();
    $scope.getorganisationUnits = function () {
        window.alert("Show data");
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" id="content">
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="selected"> Please Select Option</option>
        <option value="organisationUnits"> Organisation Units</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Go" id="getall_go" onclick="loadData1()"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the *angular way* of doing this

Comment: //angular.element('#content').scope().getorganisationUnits();

Comment: @Laurianti This is not how to work in AngularJS. Please provide correct solution for AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to do it in an *angular way*

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.load = function() {
    console.log("Dropdown value : " + $scope.drop);
    if ($scope.drop === "organisationUnits")
      console.log("Show data");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" id="content">
  <select id="dropdown" ng-model="drop">
    <option value="selected">Please Select Option</option>
    <option value="organisationUnits">Organisation Units</option>
  </select>

  <input type="button" value="Go" id="getall_go" ng-click="load()" />
</div>
```

Comment: I would add a ng-change here instead

Comment: @Groben Op's seems to load only when the button is clicked